# Restore emails from local file system to exchange account in ews api

Tags: java, api, exchangewebservices

I am trying to restore emails from local file system to any exchange account in java, I have tried with `copyItems(ItemId itemId, Destination folderId)` and `moveItems(ItemId itemId, Destination folderId)` methods of `EWS(Exchange api)` but its throws an exception as "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed", so can you please help me to resolve this..

```
 for (Object obj : emlFiles) {
      File file = (File) obj;
      InputStream source = null;
      EmailMessage message = null;
      source = new FileInputStream(file);
      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(null, source);
      message = new EmailMessage(service);
      // Set properties on the email message.
        message.ParentId = msg.getMessageID();
        ItemId id = (ItemId.getItemIdFromString(message.ParentId));
        //service is exchange service object..
        service.moveItem(id,destinationFolder.getId());
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You say you trying to restore email but what was the method you use to back them up and what format is the file in that is stored in the file System ?

Comment: I have created EmailMessage object and pass it to `moveItem()` method which is in build method of ews api, above mentioned message is object of EmailMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MoveItem won't work in this instance because you can only move an existing store item from one place to other. Just call save on the Item you created and use the destination Folder you want to save it to. eg

```
message.save(destinationFolder.getId());
```

You may also want to set the SentFlag so the message won't show as a draft eg see the example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672319(v=exchg.150).aspx

```
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
    email.SetExtendedProperty(PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS_msgflag_read, 1);
```

Cheers
Glen